# Equivalent of JOptionPane in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, user-input

I would like to use something similar to JOptionPane from Java in my Kotlin project. Are there any good alternatives to just using JOptionPane in Kotlin by calling Java from Kotlin?

Comment: Assuming this is Kotlin/JVM*, just use JOptionPane. There's no issue with calling Java from Kotlin, or vice versa — the JVM sees only classes, with no idea which language they were compiled from. (We have production projects using a mixture of Java and Kotlin, and others which were converted to Kotlin one class at a time.) (* If not, then of course it'll depend on which UI framework you're using.)

Comment: Alright then. Ill do that.